# PDO losing connection within a for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue that is driving me nuts and hoping someone can help.  I have recently started learning mysql PDO as opposed to the old method.  I have put together a form that grabs values into an array and then processes them in a loop.  I have simplified it below to show you what i'm doing but the problem is that I get it working fine on the local machine but when its loaded live i think it somehow loses the mysql connection during the for loop.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="next.php">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial;">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br/></td>
      <td><b>Sub Service Code</b></td>
      <td><b>Criteria Value</b></td>
      <td><b>Criteria Value 2</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="2" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;John</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="3" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;Paul</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="4"checked /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;Mary</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="next">
</form>
```

The php script i am using to process this form looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
?>
<form method="post" action="next-2.php">
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial;">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br/></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>Value</b></td>
<td><b>Value 2</b></td>
<td><b>Select # of Levels</b></td>
</tr>

<?php
  $id = $_POST['ID'];
  if (empty($id)) {
    echo("<p>You didn't select any names.</p>");
  } else {
    $N = count($id);
    echo("<p>You selected $N names(s):</p>");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
      //echo($id[$i] . " ");
      $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM services_main');
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if ($row['ID'] == $id[$i]) {

        echo '
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="'.$row['ID'].'" checked /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;'.$row['Name'].'</td>
  <td>&nbsp;'.$row['Value'].'</td>
  <td>&nbsp;'.$row['Value 2'].'</td>
  <td>
    <select name="rate_'.$row['ID'].'" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>                       
  </td>
</tr>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="next-2">
</form>
```

In the non-local environment, I am getting this:

```
<form method="post" action="next-2.php">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial;">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br/></td>
      <td><b>Name</b></td>
      <td><b>Value</b></td>
      <td><b>Value 2</b></td>
      <td><b>Select # of Levels</b></td>
    </tr>
    <p>You selected 3 names(s):</p>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="2" checked /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;John</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <select name="rate_2" >
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>                       
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="next-2">
</form>
```

The reason i think it may be losing the db connection is because I set it to say 'You selected $N names' and it is correctly showing 3 for the value of N meaning it should loop through 3 times querying the db each time for each of the three ID values for each name.  Again, it works perfectly fine on my local environment but not on the live server.  I can't figure out why it is only giving me back the first name result (John) and not the other two in the live environment.

Lastly, on each of my pages i am including the following db connections file

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=sitename.org;dbname=name;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'pwd');
```

I hope I've explained this question thoroughly enough and I'm guessing it's probably something simple i am overlooking somehow.  Thanks for looking at it...

Comment: What is the intention of this line: if ($row['ID'] == $id[$i])?  What happens if you comment it out?

Comment: Try adding `$stmt->closeCursor()` after the while loop.  Also, why are you fetching everything from the database for *each* ID you have?  Why not build a `SELECT * FROM services_main WHERE ID IN (...)` query?  This will execute much faster.

Comment: Where's the problem? I don't see any question here

Comment: the reason for that is that i am looking up records based on the id value submitted by the form.  i only want to show records with those ids.  if i comment that out, it will show all records from the db

Comment: @Truth The question is on the title...

Comment: @Fong-WanChau: I don't see that happening here. Where is the connection being lost? What kinds of errors is he getting? What's wrong with the output?

Comment: the problem with the output is that it is only showing the 'John' name where it should be showing the other two (Paul and Mary).  It seems to me that it loops through, grabs John (which is ID 2) and then doesn't loop through to get the others.  I don't get any error messages but i just don't get all three records back

Comment: @rob: what happens if you comment out the if condition blearn mentioned. Also you should be using a `WHERE IN` instead of running multiple queries as cdhowie mentions.

Comment: Ok, i updated the query to be $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM services_main WHERE ID IN ($id[$i])");  I also took out the  if ($row['ID'] == $id[$i]).  It is working fine (and faster thanks) locally but again, same issue on the live server.  I also tried adding $stmt->closeCursor(); immediately after the while loop and no luck

Comment: @robmelino No join the IDs together.  `"SELECT * FROM services_main WHERE ID IN (" . implode(",", $id) . ")"`.  Of course, you need to sanitize the `$id` array first (cast each element to `int` for example) to eliminate any possible SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks cdhowie, any idea why would solve the issue for the live server when the original worked on the local?  Just want to try to understand the root cause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first of all, you don't need to compare one by one record to find out the result you want, just use MySQL `WHERE` to condition your result. Other problem is about the structure, you can't add a `<p>` element into the `<table>`.

So, what I do is check is `$_POST['ID']` set, and then check is this variable is an array. Then I escaped all values of `$_POST['ID']` and after that implode the array to the SQL.

**NOTE: In the SQL, I selected only the field that your code requested.**

So, this code should work:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
?>
<form method="post" action="next-2.php">
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial;">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br/></td>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><b>Value</b></td>
<td><b>Value 2</b></td>
<td><b>Select # of Levels</b></td>
</tr>

<?php
  // Check the existence of the "$_POST['ID']" and check if this is a array
  if (isset($_POST['ID']) && is_array($_POST['ID']) {
    $id = $_POST['ID'];
    // Here we can't add '<p>' element to the table, so I used '<tr>'
    echo '<tr><td colspan="5">You selected ' . count($id) . 'names(s):</td></tr>';

    // Create a function to escape the value.
    function escape($value) {
      // Only integer value can be returned.
      return (int) $value;
    }

    // Escaping '$id' values.
    $id = array_map('escape', $id);

    // SQL, here we implode all value to the condition.
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `Value`, `Value 2` FROM `services_main` WHERE `ID` IN (' . implode(',', $id) . ')');

    // Loop all results
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="ID[]" value="' . $row['ID'] . '" checked /></td>
  <td>&nbsp;' . $row['Name'] . '</td>
  <td>&nbsp;' . $row['Value'] . '</td>
  <td>&nbsp;' . $row['Value 2'] . '</td>
  <td>
    <select name="rate_' . $row['ID'] . '" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>                       
  </td>
</tr>';
    }

    unset($stmt, $id);
  } else {
    // Here we can't add '<p>' element to the table, so I used '<tr>'
    echo '<tr><td colspan="5">You didn\'t select any names.</td></tr>';
  }
}
?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="next-2">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Fong-Wan! this seems to be working and is similar to how i adjusted code after reading cdhowie's comment.  My only issue is that I also need to echo out each row(ID) value (i didn't include this in my original posted code because i wanted to keep it simple).  since we removed the initial 'for' loop and now get the query working by imploding the values, i now can't figure out how to access each id value so that i can echo it out with every name.  In other words, you can't now do ' . $row['Name'] . '.$id[$i].'  Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: nevermind, figured it out.  i can just use $row['ID'] instead of $id[$i].  Thanks again everyone for your help!